# Restlet 1.1 Access Control Header Issue

Tags: java, jquery, restlet

I'm working on a restlet built on restlet 1.1.1

The issue I'm facing is setting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to allow for cross domain requests. I've attempted a few things that didn't work.

Method one, put the header in the acceptRepresentation function:

```
@Override
public void acceptRepresentation( Representation resetEntity ) {
    Form headers = (Form)getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");

    if (headers == null) {
        headers = new Form();
        getResponse().getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", headers);
    }
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://origin.server.edu");

    //other code here for actual resource logic...
}
```

This didn't work. I still received errors when attempting to send a request using JQuery as such:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "https://test.servername.edu/cas/cas-rest-api/reset/",
    data: JSON.stringify("{\"uname\" : \"someone\", \"attr\":\"dataElement\" }"),
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true
})
.done(function(data){
    console.log("Success");
    alert(data);
})
.fail(function(data){
    console.log("failure");
    console.log(data);
    alert(data);
});
```

This didn't work. So I noticed an init function in the resource class. I figured I'd attempt putting my code there to see if this would change the situation.

```
@Override
public void init(Context context, Request request, Response response ){
    Form headers = (Form)response.getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");

    if (headers == null) {
        headers = new Form();
        response.getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", headers);
    }
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://origin.server.edu");
    super.init(context, request, response);
}
```

Nope. Didn't work either. What am I missing here? Where do I set this header?

Comment: Your code seems fine, it should return a correct "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. Could you check that the header appears in the HTTP response? Did you try with the "*" value?

Comment: As a side note, using the release 2.3, you can use a configurable CorsService that handles all of this stuff for you (http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/introduction/whats-new/2.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. After some analysis of the problem it turned out that I needed to configure Spring to allow option requests for my restlet in the web.xml file as shown below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ccrest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.noelios.restlet.ext.spring.RestletFrameworkServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```